# Arduino WiFi - Client Read very slow

Tags: arduino, client, wifi

I want to control a servo with my Arduino UNO & Wifi shield. I wrote a Java program which is sending strings (for example: left, mid, etc...) to my Arduino (over my WLAN-Network). In my Arduino program, I read the chars with `client.read()`.

Now my problem is: When I sent a few strings to my arduino (for example: 4 times `"left"`) than it works fine, but after when I want to sent other 4 strings to right, first it keeps going left for about 4 times (sometimes more) before it changes to right. The same happend with up and down...

I really don't now why, the connection is stable and the server control programm is working fine with ethernet shield from Arduino.

Here my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>

char ssid[] = "yourNetwork"; // SSID des Netzwerkes
char pass[] = "secretPassword"; // Passwort des Netzwerkes
int keyIndex = 0; // Netzwerk Key-Index (nur bei WEP erforderlich)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

// Servo dekl.
Servo myservo1;  
Servo myservo2;  

// Achsenstand init
int iXAchse=90;
int iYAchse=90;

// Einlese-String dekl.
String readString; 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // Seriell start

    // Überprüft ob Wifi Shield angeschlossen ist
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
        Serial.println("Kein WLAN Shield verbunden!");
        while(true); // Dauer-Stop Schleife
    }

    // Verbindungsaufbau mit Netzwerk
    while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print("Verbindungsaufbau mit Netzwerk: ");
        Serial.println(ssid); // Gibt SSID des Netzwerkes aus

        // Mit WPA/WPA2 Netzwerk verbinden
        status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        // Wenn keine Verbindung - Warte 10 Sekunden
        delay(10000);
    }
    server.begin(); // Server startet

    // Nachdem WIFI seine Verbindung hergestellt hat, stelle noch Servos ein
    myservo1.write(iXAchse); // weiter oben auf 90 gesetzt
    myservo2.write(iYAchse); // weiter oben auf 90 gesetzt

    myservo1.attach(9); // Pin 9 - X Achse
    myservo2.attach(8); // Pin 8 - Y Achse
}


void loop() {
    WiFiClient client = server.available(); // listen for incoming clients

    if (client) { // Client verfügbar ? 
        while (client.connected()) { // Solange Client verfügbar
            if (client.available()) { // Wenn Client Daten schickt

                char c = client.read(); 

                if (readString.length() < 100) { 
                    readString += c;
                } 

                if (c == '\n')  {

                    Serial.println(readString);  

                    //Servo1 Bewegung
                    client.println("links");
                    client.println("mitte");
                    client.println("rechts"); 

                    //Servo2 Bewegung
                    client.println("oben");
                    client.println("mid"); 
                    client.println("unten"); 

                    //stopt client
                    client.stop();

                    ///////////////////// Steuern von den Arduino pin
                    if(readString.indexOf("rechts") >0) {
                        iXAchse+=8;
                        myservo1.write(iXAchse);
                    }
                    if (readString.indexOf("mitte") >0) {
                        myservo1.write(90);
                        iXAchse=90;
                    }
                    if(readString.indexOf("links") >0) {
                        iXAchse-=8;
                        myservo1.write(iXAchse); 
                    }
                    if(readString.indexOf("oben") >0) {
                        iYAchse+=8;
                        myservo2.write(iYAchse);
                    }
                    if(readString.indexOf("mid") >0) { 
                        myservo2.write(90);
                        iYAchse=90;
                    }
                    if(readString.indexOf("unten") >0) {
                        iYAchse-=8;
                        myservo2.write(iYAchse);
                    }         
                    readString="";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check what c is.  If it is -1 i.e. there is no input, it should be ignored.

Comment: How to check c? If c == -1 ?? Or The indexof The readString?

Comment: After the read char, add **if (c == -1) continue;**.  Not the index of read string.  It is possible that available is true but there is no data in read char yet.

Comment: unfortunally there is no change when i add this line like you recommend. :(

Answer (score 1):

The `read()` method of the `Stream` class in Arduino has a timeout (which is about one second on my Yun board). Each call to `read()` will cause a one second delay that's blocking other activities. So in your case, I believe you had a four-second delay for processing the last "l e f t".

The timeout can be changed via [`setTimeout()`](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamSetTimeout), i.e., please try `client.setTimeout(200)` in your program and see if it will become more responsive.